# Android emulator not responding for last 2 hours on mac OSX mavericks

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, haxm

I am trying to run android emulator on my mac and it is frozen for the last 2 hours. I don't know how to solve this issue, I have been trying to use this for the past week on my mac but it doesn't boot up. Here are some screenshots:

[image: This is the emulator blank screen (not responding)]

[image: These are my emulator settings that I am using to run]

I am using hotfix HAXM Intel update but it still won't work. Can anyone please help me out, It would be of tremendous help as I am unable to start working on my class project until my emulator is up and running.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try reducing the RAM size(600MB) and Internal Storage size(50MB).

Comment: While I have, occasionally, seen cutting the RAM size fix this, The thing that nearly *always* fixes it is using a smaller (WVGA800) screen size.

Comment: A combination of both the above suggestions worked!! Thank you!